# Finding maximal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am looking to find all of the maximal ideals in $\Bbb{Z}_{12}$. I have mapped out $\langle 2\rangle$, $\langle 3\rangle$, $\langle 6\rangle$, $\langle 0\rangle$. I am still confused as to whether $\langle 2\rangle$ and $\langle 3\rangle$ are maximal ideals or if $\langle 6\rangle$ is a maximal ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximal really means what it means, i.e., not included in a larger proper ideal. This rules out <6> and <0>.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

The maximal ideal in a quotient ring $R/I$ correspond bijectively to the maximal ideals in $R$ that contain $I$.